# Microsoft Exchange Integration in Python

Tags: python, outlook, odoo, exchange-server, pyexchange

Which is the good python package/library for integrating MS Exchange in Python.: **PyExchange** or **exchangelib** .

I am trying to integrate MS Exchange with Odoo 10, please advise me with the best package to do it. I tried some of the functions of **exchangelib** . eg: bulk_create, account.calendar.all(), etc and working.But some functions bulk_update, bulk_delete is not working.

Am not able to update the values from Odoo to MS Exchange calender because it shows error:

> AttributeError: 'Calendar' object has no attribute 'bulk_update'
>
> AttributeError: 'Calendar' object has no attribute 'bulk_delete'

please advise

Answer (score 0):

`bulk_update()` and `bulk_delete()` are methods on the `Account` class, not the `Folder` class. That's why you're getting the `AttributeError`.